# Spacing out every 2 characters in a string?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

my string is "37829300".

How can I space out every 2 characters in the string so the result can be "37 82 93 00".

I am trying to achieve this in vc++.

Thanks.

I understand I may have to use #include iostream but I am lost on how to do it properly.

Comment: WinForms C++/CLI or MFC VC++?

Comment: Any specific reason this is tagged "winforms"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a fancy one-liner regular-expression, so let's do it the manual way.

```
private static string AddSpaceAfterTwoDigits(string input)
{
    string output = string.Empty;
    MatchCollection arr = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d\d");
    if ( arr.Count > 0 )
    {
        output = arr[0].Groups[0].Value; // Add the first with no space

        for ( int i = 1; i < arr.Count; i++ )
        {
            output += " " + arr[i].Groups[0].Value;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

- The code is in C#, but it's a fairly straight-forward conversion to C++/CLI.
- The code assumes an input of an **even** number of **digits**.

Comment: Since I code in c#, I will try to convert to c++. I currently have 

sHexPic = string_to_hex(sPic);
  sHexPic.insert(sHexPic.begin() + 2,' ');
  sHexPic.insert(2," ");

but all this code does is input a space after the 2nd digit. I need to find a way to loop my code. Thank you for your c# code though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612079/loop-to-keep-adding-spaces-in-string

I re made a thread with my code and tried to explain my situation better.