# How to re arrange characters in a string?

Tags: c++-cli

here is the following code which works just fine:

```
sCharacterUid = "394F73";
size_t pos;
sPos1 = sCharacterUid.substr(4,1);
sPos2 = sCharacterUid.substr(5,1);
sPos3 = sCharacterUid.substr(2,1);
sPos4 = sCharacterUid.substr(3,1);
sPos5 = sCharacterUid.substr(0,1);
sPos6 = sCharacterUid.substr(1,1);
sCharacterUid = sPos1 + sPos2 + " " + sPos3 + sPos4 + " " + sPos5 + sPos6;
String^ sfCharacterUid = gcnew String(sCharacterUid.c_str());
```

but I am wondering how I can cut down the amount of code needed to perform this task.

This is in c++/cli.

Thanks.

Comment: @karlphillip: Yes and no: it's [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

Comment: Why did you not try suggestions offered in other 2 similar questions you asked - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612079/loop-to-keep-adding-spaces-in-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612079/loop-to-keep-adding-spaces-in-string)?

Comment: I did and it was for something else which works just fine.

Comment: @ruakh Ok, I updated the tags of the question to reflect the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at first glance, why not

```
sPos1 = sCharacterUid.substr(4,2); 
sPos3 = sCharacterUid.substr(2,2);
sPos5 = sCharacterUid.substr(0,2);
sCharacterUid = sPos1 + " " + sPos3 + " " + sPos5;
```

Or

```
string result="";
for (i=4;i>=0;i-=2)
  result += sCharacterUid.substr(i,2) + " ";
```

Or, it may be more efficient to work with raw chars.

```
char result=[9];
char* dest=result;
char* source = sCharacterUid.c_str();
for (i=4;i>=0;i-=2)
{
   *dest++ = source[i];
   *dest++ = source[i+1];
   *dest++ = ' ';
}
*(--dest)='\0';
String^ sfCharacterUid = gcnew String(result);
```

Comment: works just fine, I never used substr before so this works just fine! Thanks. will make answer in 5 minutes...

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string & S = sCharacterUid;
S = S.substr (4, 2) + " " + S.substr (2, 2) + " " + S.substr (0, 2);
```

Comment: @Andrew: It's not generally useful to say that something "doesn't work". Either it gives a compile error (in which case, which?), or it gives a runtime error (in which case, which?), or it does something different from what you expected (in which case, what does it do?), or it does nothing at all (in which case, say so).

Comment: I assumed sCharacterUid is a String?

Comment: @idefixs, 2 errors, error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'System::String ^' and error C2228: left of '.substr' must have class/struct/union